# Without retrieving your entire database each time an update happens, add realtime listeners

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Could you explain what does this meaning on Firestore?

> To keep data in your apps current, without retrieving your entire
>   database each time an update happens, add realtime listeners. Adding
>   realtime listeners to your app notifies you with a data snapshot
>   whenever the data your client apps are listening to changes,
>   retrieving only the new changes.

It says about this or else?

```
this.budgets$ = this.budgetProvider.getSpecificBudgetGroupBudgets(data, 
this.projectProvider.projectId).valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The realtime listeners behave as websockets, thus eliminating the need to run the same query at regular intervals to see if any data has changed.

The [Get Realtime Updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) documentation provides some good examples. Here is one of them:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

The [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onSnapshot) method attaches a listener for `DocumentSnapshot` events.

Comment: Could I have an example?

Comment: Hope you and me talk about the same thing no? I have used `angularfire2` and you showed using `Javascript SDK` no?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my misunderstanding, you're right. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges - that is more relevant to AngularFire specifically.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood, in firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) they are talking about `onSnapshot()` which is a realtime listener, and `get()` is not. `onSnapshot()` will listen to these individual document changes `added`, `removed`, and `modified` and you can listen to each cases like in this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

And `Angularfire2` is library written over these firebase native jsdk methods and do the same but will return as `Observables`. Here is what official [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#using-angularfirestorecollection) says

> The AngularFirestoreCollection service is a wrapper around the native Firestore SDK's CollectionReference and Query types. It is a generic service that provides you with a strongly typed set of methods for manipulating and streaming data. This service is designed for use as an @Injectable().

Here is the return type [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/firestore/collection/collection.ts)

`valueChanges(events?: firebase.firestore.DocumentChangeType[]): Observable<T[]>;`

`DocumentChangeType[]` has following arguments

```
export type DocumentChangeType = 'added' | 'removed' | 'modified';
```